# Is the window handle (HWND) of a window persistent across hibernation?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, findwindow, hibernation

Is the window handle (HWND) of a window (especially *Windows Notepad*) persistent during the lifetime of the window, especially across hibernation?

Say I write a programm that retrieves (eg using [FindWindowEx-function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa)) and saves the handle of a specific window of another programm (in my case the window of a Windows Notepad).

Then the pc is hibernated and dehibernated/started again.

*After the start/"dehibernation" the window of the other programm still exists, but will its window handle (HWND) still be the same?*

(E.g. important because my programm wants to use the handle of the other window to perform some action with the other window like retrieve its content).

Thanks for any help

Comment: Generally yes HWNDs persist.  But the other application may recreate it's Windows after being restored from hibernation.  So I can't answer for a specific unknown application.  Use an application like Spy++ to check the specific application.

Comment: @Richard Critten
Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you know if it is persistent for the built-in Windows Notepad?
(So i open a Windows Notepad, type something in it, then hibernate and start again/"dehibernate": Will the Notepad (with the same content) still have the same window handle?)

Comment: @user - what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @selbie I'm trying to write a programm that saves open windows-notepads in a specific folder. The programm should run roughly every minute and also save old versions of the same note, but i don't know if that still works if i hibernate inbetween

Comment: @selbie (Later i want to extend it to do different things depending of the fate on the notepad, eg if it was saved with a name i will delete my saved copy, if its closed by user with the x-button by the user without saving then i want to copy it to a different subfolder, if the pc crashed (all windows disappear at the same time) then i want to restore it etc
Basically i like using Windows Notepad (and don't like various note-taking programms i tried) but my notepads often disappear when the pc crashes/gets a bluescreen. The hibernation part is one aspect of the programm)

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to replace notepad by a program that creates the backups as needed? What you do sounds quite brittle to me. MS may change or replace notepad at any time.

Comment: @user If you only do it once a minute, just call `FindWindowEx` every time instead of saving the handle.

Comment: What if there is more than one instance of Notepad running?  What's the plan then?

Comment: @PaulSanders could save the process ID/handle of the intended Notepad, and then find the window that belongs to that process. Even if the window is recreated after hibernation, the process won't be.

Answer (score 0):

As far as hibernation is concerned, it won't change according to [Resuming from hibernation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-states#resuming-from-hibernation).

> **restoring the contents of memory and all architectural registers**. In
> the case of a resume from hibernation, the contents of the system
> memory are read back in from the disk, decompressed, and restored,
> which puts the system in the **exact** state it was in when it was
> hibernated.